# qemu on Raspberry Pi Arch Linux latest sd image

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, qemu, raspbian

I am trying to set up an Arch image and use qemu in order to cross-compile some stuff before I load the image onto the Pi.  I thought the easiest way to do it would be to qemu the latest starter image, prepare it with whatever I needed, and then dd it onto the Pi when I was done.

I downloaded the Arch image from http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/arch_latest, and wanted to run it under Qemu similar to http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/.

I tried many variations on the qemu command line they gave

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

substituting the archlinux-hf-2013-07-22.img.  But this eventually led to "Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel"

I'm sure this means the kernel-qemu I downloaded won't work with the Arch image, but I'm not sure the right way to fix the issue.

**Edit:**

Even the latest Raspbian image kernel panics when I use the command line above with it.  Which I guess shouldn't have surprised me, since it's most likely an old kernel.

So I guess my real question is, how can I use whatever kernel is included in the image, rather than having to build my own kernel?

Comment: Xecdesign is 404, https://web.archive.org/web/20150512213356/http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/#more-45 the comments found you needed to comment out /etc/ld.so.preload for qemu to work on raspberry pi for raspbian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case archlinux-hf-2013-07-22.img
Here there 3 partion are made.
you can check by using

`fdisk -l archlinux-hf-2013-07-22.img`

`rootfs is in sd5 i.e 5th partion.`

So pass this parameter `"root=/dev/sda5 panic=1"` , it will boot perfectly.

Comment: This worked.  Maybe combine contents with your other answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In  `2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`
You can use same kernel for both image.

Here you have to comment `ld.so.preload` which will load some shared-library,which will unable login. so kernel panic.

`Note:-"root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" pass this parameter only.`

You can comment it by doing below.

`sudo kpartx -av 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

`mkdir tmp`

`sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 tmp/`

`cd tmp/etc`

`sudo vi ld.so.preload`
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
comment

`#/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so`

`umount /dev/mapper/loop0p2`
`kpartx -d 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

Then run qemu

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

this will perfectly boot without any trouble

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked yet.  I ended up just using the Pi for compilation, but will check this as may need to use qemu in future.

Comment: Using kpartx to comment out the line in ld.so.preload allowed me to boot Raspbian on Qemu in Linux Mint 17.